# Matrices that have the same fundamental subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If matrices $A$ and $B$ have the same fundamental subspace than $A=cB$ where $c$ is some scalar.

I think it is true, because I try to disprove with this two matrices, they have the same dimension of fundamental subspace, but I think in this question want that we have the same vector in fundamental space of matrices. So than is true that exist c.

> A=$\begin{bmatrix}
>     1& 0& 0\\
>     0& 1& 0\\
>     0 & 0& 1\\
>     0 & 0& 2
>    \end{bmatrix}$.
>   B=$\begin{bmatrix}
>     3& 0& 0\\
>     0& 2& 0\\
>     0 & 0& 1\\
>     0 & 0& 2
>    \end{bmatrix}$.

But what do you think?

Comment: What do you mean with fundamental subspace? Also, in your case $A\neq cB$ for any $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by fundamental subspace you mean the space generated by rows and the kernel of $A$ and $A^t$ as stated [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalMatrixSubspaces.html) then your assertion is false. Consider
$$
 A = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \qquad
 B = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Those two have the same fundamental spaces but there exists no $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A = cB$

Comment: I think that everything is the same but $R(A)=(0,1)$ and $R(B)=(1,0)$ so they do not have the same fundamental subspaces everything other is the same but there is different

Comment: what is $R(A)$?

Comment: Image of linear transformation

Comment: image of what transfomation? The induce one from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: It does not write a dimension but I understand that you choose a some matrices and you just change one entrie and you still have the same fundamental subspace, but c does not exist since you if you multiply with c you do not change one entries you change every entries so it muss not exist some c such that A=cB